# django send_mail has insecure link to http://dpaste.com/

Tags: django

I am trying to send emails with django and for that I use send_email from django.core.mail, but it has a link to http://dpaste.com/, with HTTP and my website is in HTTPS.

This is the message I get in my console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://b...' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form that targets an insecure endpoint 'http://dpaste.com/'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.
```

It means that the standard send_mail from django blocks my secure connection? How can that be possible? What othe solutions do I have to send email with django?

Thanks

Comment: May be one of your add-ons

Comment: No, because if I remove the import send_mail, the issue disappears. Thanks

Comment: can u remove non-std addons & see if issue disappears?

Comment: But if I remove the import send_mail from django.core.mail only, the issue already dissapears. So it can only be coming from this. Also, I searched dpaste on modules and I found it in a block of code for email.

Comment: I found dpaste in a single module: django.views.debug  -- seems to be doing some kind of logging

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: You are right, dpaste was coming because I left DEBUG TRUE. As soon as I turned it off, the problem is solved. Thanks, Suresh

Comment: Hi, dpaste.com owner here to add that as of 2020, dpaste.com uses TLS, and the [Django debug page that posts to it](https://github.com/django/django/blob/36cd4259438f98e74e472e232307a1909f164e56/django/views/templates/technical_500.html#L289) has been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was happening because I had DEBUG: TRUE and there was an error in the code. Therefor, django was using dpaste to throw the error.

The solution was to turn the DEBUG off or fix the error in the code.

Thanks, Suresh, for helping me on that.

Comment: Indeed, are you using django-debug-toolbar, I guess the url is from there. Django Debug Toolbar was enabled for me when DEBUG = True.